# how to use time to count how many seconds you logged in

Tags: php, mysql, time

Let's say I have a user/pass to enter and once it's entered another page will be redirected and in that profile page will show a line sayingi you have been staying here for xxx seconds.

I am new in PHP MySQL I have website called itube.one I already created login/register system. I need some tutorials or sothing showing exactly what i want i cant fit this script to my site I am using PHP 5.6

```
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION["username"])))
{
    header("location: index.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION["username"] . "<br/>";
    echo "You have been logged in for " . $_SESSION["timeLogged"] . " seconds.";
}
```

Comment: currenttime - userlogintime

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code I assume that in your login code you are setting this:

```
$_SESSION['timeLogged'] = time();
```

Then in your subsequent pages you can use this:

```
$timeSinceLogged = time() - $_SESSION["timeLogged"];
echo "You have been logged in for " . $timeSinceLogged . " seconds.";
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, you have to save the time of the login somewhere, in a session variable, or in a database. It's a good practice to keep track of your user's logins, so it's a good idea, to save it in a database, with some other info, like the user's ip address, session id, or even the client metadata find in the [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function. (Keep in mind, you need an up-to-date `php_browscap.ini` to get accurate info.)

But for the examples sake, set a session variable, after the login is authed:

```
//  start session
session_start();

//  set the logintime
$_SESSION['LoginTime'] = time();
```

After you got that, you just need to subtract the time of the login, from the current time:
`$time_logged_in_secs = time() - $_SESSION['LoginTime'];`

With this, you will get the time the user is logged in, in seconds.
Now you can format it any way you want.

Comment: I don't know, if the session is started anywhere previously, but in this case, it might be unnecessary.

Comment: You're right, I switched up the args in my subtraction, edited it. And removed the condition from the session start. I hope, now it's good.

Comment: My concern, now, is that your method is now a later duplicate of @davidethell's.

Comment: Yeah, by 15 secs :D And I think I explained it a bit better.

Comment: The time comparison is on the point of update.  You were beaten by 15 minutes it seems.  Racing to post incorrect methods should count against you, not for you. Adding extra considerations doesn't necessarily mean "explaining better".